# How to draw a boxplot whose staples looks like a square bracket in R

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot

How to draw a box plot like this:

[image: box plot drew by R]

make the staples, the mark of data within 1.5 IQR of the lower/upper quartile, looks like a square bracket.

I tried:

```
bx = sapply(5:1, function(x) rnorm(100, x, sqrt(x)))

boxplot(bx, col = "gray", pch = "", boxwex = 0.3,
  medlwd = rep(3, 4), medcol = rep("white", 4),
  outlty = 1, outwex = 1, 
  whisklty = 1, 
  staplelty = 1, staplewex = 1,
  names = paste0("mu = ", 5:1))

title(main = "n = 100")
```

[image]

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to do this with `staplelty`.  However,  you can just draw the staple as a horizontal line and add the vertical ticks.

```
boxplot(iris[,1:4], outlty=1, pch="")

for(i in 1:4) {
    segments(c(i-0.2,i+0.2), BP$stats[5,i], c(i-0.2,i+0.2), BP$stats[5,i] - 0.1)
    segments(c(i-0.2,i+0.2), BP$stats[1,i], c(i-0.2,i+0.2), BP$stats[1,i] + 0.1)
}
```

[image: Boxplot with Fancy Staples]

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't expect anyone can answer this "weird" question.